# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of large matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Is it somehow possible to obtain the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of very large matrices similar to the one below analytically ?
$$X=
{\begin{bmatrix}
6a & -3b & 0 & 0 & -3b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-\sqrt{3}b & 5a & -2b & 0 & -b & -\sqrt{2}b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -2b & 8a & -\sqrt{3}b & 0 & -\sqrt{2}b & -b & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -\sqrt{3}b & 15a & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{3}b & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-\sqrt{3}b & -b & 0 & 0 & 5a & -\sqrt{2}b & 0 & -2b & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\sqrt{2}b & -\sqrt{2}b & 0 & -\sqrt{2}b & 5a & -\sqrt{2}b & -\sqrt{2}b & -\sqrt{2}b & 0\\
0 & 0 & -b & -\sqrt{3}b & 0 & -\sqrt{2}b & 9a & 0 & -2b & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2b & -\sqrt{2}b & 0 & 8a & -b & -\sqrt{3}b\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2}b & -2b & -b & 9a & -\sqrt{3}b\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{3}b & -\sqrt{3}b & 15a
\end{bmatrix}}
$$

Is it really possible to find exact solutions of such large matrices, if not how do I know I can't ?

**Note:** $a$, $b$ are constants

Comment: I doubt it, because it would be a $10^{th}$ order equation to find the roots of. I tried with Mathematica and it can find four of four of the eigenvalues and those are ugly! Can you say anything more about the constants $a, b$?

Comment: @Moo $a,b$ are real constants and their values are totally independent.

Comment: Then, I doubt you will find closed form solution and are stuck with numerical methods based on knowing specific choices of said variables.

Comment: @Moo ok. So if we know the value of $a$ and $b$ then is it possible to find an exact answer without using any numerical techniques ?

Comment: You are dealing with a tenth order equation, so likely not. For example, I just tried $a = b = 1$ and still cannot get an exact solution, but it gets the numerical result almost immediately.